# Fetch Browser history details from browser other than default in android

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app in which i need to fetch the URL's that are accessed by the user. I've successfully fetched the URL's from android's default browser. I know that some browsers are protective towards this act. But i need to know whether there's any work around that could succeed this objective. Mainly from opera and dolphin browser

Comment: have you find the solution?

Comment: @maddy: Nope. We cannot access the data from other browsers. Default browsers let you to observe the data through content observer. But no other browsers would let us to observe.